# Alternative expression for Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections, general-relativity, supergeometry

There is the usual expression for the Riemann tensor

$$R_{abcd}=\partial_c\Gamma_{adb}-\partial_d\Gamma_{acb}+\Gamma_{ace}{\Gamma^e}_{db}-\Gamma_{ade}{\Gamma^e}_{cb}.$$
However, in the last page of [https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~walcher/teaching/wise1516/geo_phys/SigmaAndLGModels.pdf](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ewalcher/teaching/wise1516/geo_phys/SigmaAndLGModels.pdf), another expression is used

$$R_{abcd}=\partial_c\Gamma_{adb}-\partial_d\Gamma_{acb}+\Gamma_{ead}{\Gamma^e}_{cb}-\Gamma_{eac}{\Gamma^e}_{db}.$$

How does one obtain the first expression from the second? I've never seen the second expression before. The first one is obvious from the expression $R=\text{d}\Gamma-[\Gamma\wedge\Gamma]$. However, the second one is less intuitive. In orthogonal coordinates it would be easy to obtain since
$$\Gamma_{abc}=-\Gamma_{bac}.$$
However, is there a way to see this two expression are equivalent without using orthogonality? I think it will have to do with the metricity condition
$$\partial_ag_{bc}=\Gamma_{bca}-\Gamma_{cba}.$$

Bonus question: How do you do index placement in stackexchange?

Comment: It was solved in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699707/alternative-expression-for-riemann-curvature-tensor/699730#699730

Answer (score 1):

The metric tensor $g_{fe}$ is used to lower the index $f$ and rename it to $e$:
$$
g_{fe}\Gamma^f_{md}=\Gamma_{emd}\,.
$$
and $g^{am}$ is used to raise $m$ and rename it to $a$.
Try to apply this to the expression $\Gamma^f_{md}\Gamma^e_{cb}-\Gamma^f_{mc}\Gamma^e_{db}\,.$ It must also have some symmetry properties which should finally give the first expression.

Index placement I always to like this: `${R^a}_{bcd}$`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem I am having is precisely, how to turn an expression like $\Gamma_{eab}{\Gamma^{e}}_{cd}$ into something like $\Gamma_{aeb}{\Gamma^{e}}_{ab}$. In doing so I obtain a derivative $\partial_b g_{ae}{\Gamma^{e}}_{cd}$ that I don't know how to get rid of in the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on index placement! I've used them to appropriately raise and lower all indices to make my question clearer!

Comment: @IvanBurbano . Looks like you solved it. Note that a single Cristoffel symbol is not a tensor. That's why many authors (most?) don't use index placement for them. Only for real tensors like $R$. The GR book by Sean Carroll explains this well.

Comment: The GR book by Sean Carroll explains this well. See also [arXiv:gr-qc:9712019](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019).